# Problems using WooCommerce & Qstomizer

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In my site:

> Warning:  Missing argument 3 for
>   Qstomizer::qsmz_change_product_image_thumbnail_html() in
>   /home/grafixcordoba/public_html/corp/wp-content/plugins/qstomizer-custom-product-designer/qstomizer.php

Could anyone help me?

Comment: yeah but I like this plugin x,x but... thanks I will have to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This plugin hasn’t been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be
>   maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used
>   with more recent versions of WordPress.